# Using strtok() to store numeric values in a 2D array

Tags: c, strtok

I'm trying to write a program that takes a list of numbers from a file and stores each row of numbers in a 2D array using strtok(). The problem I'm having is that when I try to store values in the rows of my 2D array, the while loop goes into an infinite loop, but when i use the line token = strtok(NULL, " ") to stop the loop, I just store the first value of each line into the first cell of each column.

What am I doing wrong? Heres is my code

```
int main() {
  int myArray[240][30];
  char line[240];
  char *token;
  int i, n, j;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("array_list.txt", "rt");
  j = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    token = strtok(line, " ");

    while (token != NULL) {
      n = atoi(token);
      myArray[i][j] = n;
      token = strtok(line, " ");
      printf("%d ", myArray[i][j]);
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      j++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of the file I'm trying to read.

1 98 48 55 46 12 48 43 7 73 47 33
                                                                                                                                                                    97 26 67 25 67 47 46 74 67 43 78 98 90 58 6 5 53 19 37 42
81 84 36 70 59 65 99 56 94 23
79 73 27 47 98 78 8 2 3 43 84 19 59 98 51 72 2 13 55 3
20 61 25 84 28 70 56 23 52 69
86 70 60 90 72
51 71 92 91 55 6 72 67 73 64 78 43 65 30 49
99 82 40 72 5 44 20 21 22 72 99 74 27 59 25 1 26 26 22 66
63 27 54 46 46
91 65 77 45 94 94 95 11 77 46 64 14
69 70 75 48 68 22 55 78 1 4
31 76 55 12 93

Comment: do `token = strtok(line, " ");` once, then loop on `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` until it returns `NULL`, that's how it works, else you're rearming strtok with the start of the line.

Comment: `strtok()` is a 2nd class tool to look for `int`, use `strtol()`.

Answer (score 3):

there are multiple issues here.

First `j=0` must be done after `fgets` or it's never reset.

Second, the biggest error is that when you do `strtok(line," ")` you're initializing `strtok` state machine, and you must loop using `NULL` as first argument until `strtok` returns `NULL`, but you're not doing that: you're looping on both calls. AS an improvement, pass multiple choices as a separator: linefeed, tabulation, and space.

So the second time the string is already tokenized and the loop ends, but with only the first item.

Also, you have to store the value of `j` for each line, else you lose track of how many elements there are on each line (since it's variable). In the code below, I'm using the first position to store the size, then come the items.

My fix proposal (tested & works on your data):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    const char *spaces = "\n\t ";
    int myArray[240][30];
    char line[240];
    char *token;
    int i, n, j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("array_list.txt", "rt");
    i = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        j = 1;
        token = strtok(line, spaces);  // initialize line tokens
        while(token)  // won't enter if the line is empty, and stops when no more tokens
        {
            n = atoi(token);  // strtol + error checking would be better
            myArray[i][j] = n;
            j++;
            printf("%d ", myArray[i][j]);
            token = strtok(NULL, spaces);  // next token
        }
        myArray[i][0] = j;  // use first array position to store the size

        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program is still missing a few things:

- protecting against "too many elements for array". If you have too many elements in your text file (too many lines / too many items in one line) you can corrupt your memory. Check `i` & `j` & abort if they're going past the limits.
- `atoi` has no error checking, so entering "whatever" leads to a 0 value. `strtol` allows error checking.

Comment: Additionally, include `errrno.h` and `limits.h` and replace `n = atoi(token);` with `errno = 0; long tmp = strtol (token); if (errno) { /* handle error */ }; if (tmp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < tmp) { /* handle tmp too large */ }; n = (int)tmp;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah, `atoi` sucks, `strtok` super-sucks . But let OP learn. Good answer of yours.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I always shake my head when I see it. It should be labeled "*for basic example purposes only...*" It must be in a whole lot of books,  because you see it so often `:)`

Comment: should go to the trash next to `gets` and K&R C.

Comment: Note: OP's file (viewable in the editor) appears to have a blank line.  So this code may call `n = atoi(NULL);` (Cancel that - instead code is doing `atoi("\n")`.  Suggest `while(1)` --> `while(token)`.  Also the `j++` being after the `if (token==NULL) break;` is too late as it  makes for an off by one if `j` was used after the while loop as a token count.

Comment: Rather than `strtok(..., " ");` use `strtok(..., " \n");` to avoid `atoi("\n");`

Comment: "tested & works on your data" results in an extra 0 if the line does not end with a digit-`'\n` but with digit-spaces-`'\n`.

Comment: @chux: the token count idea was added afterwards. Of course, you're right for your 3 comments. Edited to store the number of items in the first position of each row.

Comment: Nice improvement. BTW `if (token==NULL) break;` not needed.

Comment: thanks. Removed (for once a conditional `while` makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

While you can use `strtok` to split words in your file and then use `atoi` to perform the conversion to `int`, there are significant drawbacks to that approach. First and foremost, `atoi` (and all the `atoX` functions) provide absolutely no way to validate whether you actually converted `atoi(word)` to a number. (Is it really `0`? -- or did the conversion just fail?)

Further, `strtok` + `atoi` is part of what `strtol` does for you. The rest of what `long strtol (const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)` does for you is provide extensive error checking through `errno`, and range checking returning `LONG_MIN` on *underflow* and `LONG_MAX` on *overflow*. It provides further checking by setting `endptr = nptr` in the case no digits were found during conversion. Even better, when the conversion succeeds, `endptr` is set to the next character following the last character that was converted. (it sets you up for your next read!)

Further, with minimal effort, you can test whether the next character should be skipped before calling `strtol` again, allowing you to parse numbers from the file regardless of what is contained in the file. In other words, you can write an integer read routine once, and then use it with minimum modification for reading whatever file you are given.

While you do not specify how you want to fill `myArray[240][30];` from the 144-values you show for your file, the following example shows you how to read those values (and values from just about any file) into an array. You need only add an additional counter or loop to put x-number of values per-row in your array, etc..

Use the constants provided for you in the various header files (e.g. `errno.h`, `limits.h`) to help you with your task. The following example reads from the filename  given on the command line (or from `stdin` by default if no filename is given) and will read any integer found in the file into the array `arr` up to a maximum of `1024` values, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for strtol */
#include <string.h>     /* for strlen */
#include <limits.h>     /* for INT_MIN, INT_MAX */
#include <errno.h>      /* for errno */

#ifndef BUF_SIZ         /* set input buffer size */
#define BUF_SIZ 8192    /* gcc default, cl.exe (VS) uses 512 */
#endif

#define BASE 10         /* conversion base 10 */
#define AMAX 1024       /* max number of values to read */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int arr[AMAX] = {0},            /* array to hold values */
        n = 0;                      /* number of values read */
    char buf[BUF_SIZ] = "";         /* line buffer */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, BUF_SIZ, fp)) {      /* read each line */
        char *p = buf,                      /* pointer to buf */
            *ep = p;                        /* end pointer for strtol */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);          /* length of buf */

        /* validate complete line read */
        if (len == BUF_SIZ - 1 && buf[len - 1] != '\n') {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line too long.\n");
            break;
        }

        while (n < AMAX && *p) {    /* n < AMAX & each starting char */
            errno = 0;                          /* reset errno */
            long tmp = strtol (p, &ep, BASE);   /* convert to long */

            /* validate conversion */
            if (p != ep) {                  /* digits converted */
                /* if no error and in range - assign to array */
                if (!errno && INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX)
                    arr[n++] = (int)tmp;
                p = ep;     /* set p to 1-past converted string */
            }

            /* find beginning of next number in buf */
            for (; *p; p++) {
                if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')  /* positive value */
                    break;          /* explicitly signed value */
                if ((*p == '+' || *p == '-') && '0' <= *(p+1) && *(p+1) <= '9')
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* output values read */
        printf (" arr[%3d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

This way, you can read from just about any file containing integer values. The following files all contain the same 10-integer values. The read does not require a POSIX EOF for the read of the last value in the file to succeed (e.g. `'\n'` following the last line). Each of the files below are read and properly parsed by the code above -- without modification.

```
$ cat dat/10int_comma.txt
8572,-2213,6434,16330,3034,12346,4855,16985,11250,1495

$ cat dat/10int.csv
8572, -2213, 6434, 16330, 3034
12346, 4855, 16985, 11250, 1495

$ cat dat/10int_5x2.txt
[[  8572  -2213  ]
 [  6434  16330  ]
 [  3034  12346  ]
 [  4855  16985  ]
 [ 11250   1495  ]]

$ cat dat/10intmess.txt
8572,;a -2213,;--a 6434,;
a- 16330,;a

- The Quick
Brown%3034 Fox
12346Jumps Over
A
4855,;*;Lazy 16985/,;a
Dog.
11250
1495
```

**Example Use/Output**

The output produced by reading each of the files above is the same.

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol <dat/10intmess.txt
 arr[  0] = 8572
 arr[  1] = -2213
 arr[  2] = 6434
 arr[  3] = 16330
 arr[  4] = 3034
 arr[  5] = 12346
 arr[  6] = 4855
 arr[  7] = 16985
 arr[  8] = 11250
 arr[  9] = 1495
```

While you are free to use `strtok` and `atoi`, the C library provides a tool for that job in `strtol` (and for all the different numeric types in the remaining `strtoX` functions). Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: `if (p == ep) p++;` makes some sense, but not `if (errno || ...)  p++;`.  On overflow, should handle like `p = ep;`.  Still, nice to look for troublesome data.

Comment: The "find beginning of next number in buf" `for()` loops seems unnecessary.  Consider just consuming white-space instead.

Comment: Agreed. For regular files it is not required as you point out, it was provided to enable reading files like the the `10intmess.txt` above where input file format may contain some combination of row-names, extraneous punctuation, etc..

Comment: OK, yet I think  `if (... p == ep)  p++;` and `for (; *p; p++) { ...` both handle (consume) the extraneous text.

Comment: Ah, I got you. That was to explicitly handle `'--'` prefixes (and the like), but since that is also covered in the `for`, you are entirely correct here. That check existed before the `for` in a version that used `strpbrk` with `"+-0123456789"` which needed the `p++` to handle the `--` case,

Comment: @chux, thank you, eliminated the cruft and turned the test around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159190/discussion-between-chux-and-david-c-rankin).

Answer (score 0):

I think OP has been given some subtly tricky input.

What looks like 6 lines of input may be something else.  Although I edited OP's post, I stayed away from the `"array_list.txt"` data section as in the editor, it *appears* to have lines with spaces after the last number, a blank line, and maybe a line with more than 30 numbers.

In other words, `"array_list.txt"` may not be as well formatted as first thought and code needs to take defensive action to avoid over-runs, etc.

---

**Set up constants**

The magic numbers 240, 30, 240 carry little meaning and since 2 numbers are the same value, there role in code can get muddled - use constants.

```
//int myArray[240][30];
//char line[240];
#define LINE_N 240
#define INT_PER_LINE_N 30

// I think this should be more like (INT_PER_LINE_N * 13)
#define LINE_SIZE 240

int myArray[LINE_N][INT_PER_LINE_N];
char line[LINE_SIZE];
```

**Prefer `strtol()` over `strtok()`**

`strtok()` is fine looking for tokens.  Code supplies a delimiter set like `" \n\t"` and life is good.  Yet what to do with non-delimiters, non-numerics?  `strtol()` handles that well for integers.

```
for (i=0; i<LINE_N; i++ {  // Do not read too many lines
  myArray[i][0] = 0;
  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
    char *p = line;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < (INT_PER_LINE_N - 1) && *p) {
      char *endptr;
      errno = 0;
      long value = strtol(p, &endptr);
      if (p == endptr) {  // no conversion
        p++; // TBD code, for now, simple advance to the next character; 
      } else {
        if (errno || value < INT_MIN || value > INT_MAX) {  // some overflow?
          ; // TBD code: for now, ignore out of range int
        } else {
          myArray[i][++j] = (int) value;
        }
        p = endptr;  // go to text after this numeric token 
      }
      // Consume trailing white-space, helps code get to the string end better
      while (isspace((unsigned char)*p) p++;
    }  
    myArray[i][0] = j;
  } // end for
}
```